# Parsing Address in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Any help is appreciated here.

I am in need of a MYSQL solution that can take an address such as 123 ABC Street and return it into 2 pieces. I need the House number on 1 lines, and the street on the other line. So Line1 = '123' and Line2 = 'ABC Street'.  Now that is a simplistic example and we may see no numerics at all, etc. I know there is no silver bullet in address parsing, I've looked at geocoders and going that route doesn't seem possible in my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look like something that MySQL was built for. Why not use any programming language for this?

Comment: The platform I'm doing this in is based on MYSQL, at the present time, that needs to be where it has to happen, otherwise I'd just use a geocode to parse. So, I'm confined to MYSQL now.

Comment: From its earliest design over 40 years ago, SQL was intended to be used together with another application language. SQL itself is not a good language for parsing. I agree with Nico, you need to do this in an application.

Comment: @CarlL. Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.